# Source code for device names

Tags: udev, devices

On a linux system many [device names](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apcs04.html) can be seen under `/dev`. This must be defined somewhere in the linux kernel source code, the udev code, device trees or driver code.

For example, where is the source code located that determines a floppy drive should start with `fd` or that a hard disk starts with `sd` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [LXR (Linux cross reference) project](http://lxr.free-electrons.com) where you can select your kernel version and search the code.

(Note: The old http://lxr.linux.no doesn't work properly anymore, at least for me; search is broken for newer kernel versions.)

Searching for "floppy" (without quotes) and a couple of attempts peeking into the results grepping for "fd" (with quotes) led me to the implementation of the floppy block device (here in kernel 4.9):

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/block/floppy.c#L4219

Now being a crossreference you can follow `register_blkdev` to its other places of use.

Answer (score 3):

An easier one to find might be something like `/dev/null` or `/dev/zero`.  For those, take a look at `${kernel_root}/drivers/char/mem.c`.  For 4.9.6 (and it's probably been this way for a while now), there's an array of `struct memdev` named `devlist`, where each entry in the array corresponds to a memory device:

```c
...
[3] = { "null", 0666, &null_fops, 0 },
...
[5] = { "zero", 0666, &zero_fops, 0 },
...
```

The `null_fops` and `zero_fops` contain the file operation structures for the corresponding devices.